# SQL sum amount that lies between two dates

Tags: sql, date, sum, between

I have the following table in SQL:

```
Start            -           End                 -          Amount **per day**
06.07.2020                   10.07.2020                     10
08.07.2020                   08.07.2020                     5
08.07.2020                   15.07.2020                     20
02.07.2020                   06.07.2020                     3
```

Now I want to filter this table by the calendar week. Let's say "where [calendar week] = cw28". cw28 is from the 06th of july to the 12th of july.

With that I'd like to have the sum of the amount of the days that lie between those two dates. One single number.

I'm using MS SQL Server (SQL Express).
I can't figure out how to distinguish (and break down) if one day lays between the two date values or not. And if yes how much I need to sum up.

I tried to make a picture in excel to create a logic from this:
["Logic" in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT2jw.png)

Can anyone help me with this? :)

Thx and Best!,
Max

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not code writing service.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Hi everybody. Thx for the replies. I updated the description. Sorry for the failure.

Comment: @Arvo: I'm already stucked with the "logic" how to figure out how many days e.g. from the 08.07.2020 - 15.07.2020 lie/intersect with the cw28 (06.07.-12.07.) My thought was: If I know the number of days that intersect with the cw28-"intervall" I can multiply this with the "Amount per day"

Comment: Well :) Generally you need calendar table - some object, containing ALL dates - you can join your table to calendar easily (calendar.day between yourtable.start and yourtable.end) and check week number on calendar table. Your specific question can be solved with recursive CTE too, but usually calendar table is more flexible and universal approach. Here on SO are many examples to even build calendar table on the fly.

Comment: What results do you want?  Desired results is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact requirement. But below is the query to get the sum of values between two dates.

```
select sum(amount_of_days) from table where date_column between '06-JUL-2020' and '07-JUL-2010';
```

Change the column name and table name according to your requirement

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. Not exactly what I need. I added a picture in my description to make it more clear. But thank you anyway :)